# Unexpected result of increments sum

Tags: javascript, increment

Good afternoon, please explain why, when waiting for 3, 4 is output to the console.

```
let x = 1;
console.log (x++ + ++x) // 4
```

At first, I thought that the priority of operations, but then why in such an example outputs 8, and not 6 for example?

```
let x = 1;
console.log (x++ + ++x + ++x) // 8
```

Sorry, if this question is duplicated, but I can't find any about this question.

Comment: `x++ + ++x` is 1 + 3, which is 4. `x++ + ++x + ++x` is 1 + 3 + 4, which is 8. Do you know the difference between pre- and post-increment?

Comment: x++ adds 1 to x after its call, so when you are calling the next ++x, it is really ++(x+1)

Comment: Yes, I know about increments, but I missed, that we operate with X variable)

Answer (score 4):

For the first example:

```js
let x = 1;
console.log (x++ + ++x) // 4
```

1. `x++` returns the value of `x` (1) and increments it afterward. `x` is now `2`. (This is postfix increment.)
2. `++x` increments the value of `x` and returns it, which is 3 (2 + 1). (This is prefix increment.)
3. 1 + 3 = 4

See [Increment Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment).

Comment: Omg, it was so easy... Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

`x++` or `x--` is first *use* then *update*. 
`++x` or `--x` is first *update* then *use*.

*update* means update the value of the variable `x`.